# dll and C++ некорректный результат

Tags: c++, dll

Начинаю изучать, что такое dll и с чем его едят. В vs2008 написал пробную dll - посмотреть, как работать с массивами. В итоге при использовании dll-ки получается абракадабра...

Вот код dll:

```
//mydll.h
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int* sum();

//mydll.cpp
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "mydll.h"

using namespace std;
int* sum()
{
    int s[5];
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
        s[i]=i;


    return s;
}
```

Дальше код, где подключается dll:

```
//mydllapp
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "windows.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

typedef int* (*P_Sum)();

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    HINSTANCE hSimplex = ::LoadLibrary(L"mydll.dll");
    P_Sum pSum = (P_Sum)::GetProcAddress(hSimplex, "sum");
    int* mas=pSum();        

    int k0=mas[0];
    int k1=mas[1];
    int k2=mas[2];
    int k3=mas[3];
    int k4=mas[4];
    int i=0;
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        cout<<mas[i]<<" ";

    }

    cout<<endl;
    cout<<k0<<endl;
    cout<<k1<<endl;
    cout<<k2<<endl;
    cout<<k3<<endl;
    cout<<k4<<endl;
    ::FreeLibrary(hSimplex);
    return 0;
}
```

В итоге на консоль выводится следующее:

> 0 1245096 4280280 4278017 1245032
>   0
>   1
>   2
>   3
>   4

Но по идее должно получаться так:

> 0 1 2 3 4
>   0
>   1
>   2
>   3
>   4

Подскажите, в чем причина и где ошибка?

Answer (score 2):

Вы возвращаете указатель на массив, память для которого выделяется в функции

```
int* sum()
{
    int s[5];
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++) s[i]=i;
    return s;
}
```

После выхода из функции, память, выделенная в стэке для массива s вообще говоря, освобождается.

Comment: почему тогда переменные k0,k1,k2,k3,k4 нормально инициализируются????
и при выводе в цикле 0-й элемент выводится??

Comment: потому что такому поведению даже имя дали - UB : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior
;)

Comment: <i>почему тогда переменные k0,k1,k2,k3,k4 нормально инициализируются????</i><p>
потому что в ТОТ момент времени содержимое стека еще живо.<p>
А cout<< между прочим это по сути вызов функции соответствующего класса. Вот стек и загаживается.<p>
Минимальное решение проблемы - сделать массив int s[5] глобальным для библиотеки.

Answer (score 1):

1. Замечание про локальный массив (уже писали).
2. Определение прототипа должно выглядеть так (тоже уже писали): `typedef int (*P_Sum)();`
3. Результат вызова функции сохранять не в "`int mas`" а в "`int *mas`": `int *mas = pSum();`

Comment: 2 Admin  Косяки какие-то у вас. Текст отображается не так как вводится. В моем посте часть звездочек потерялась :)

Comment: если бы ты комментарии почитал, то увидел бы, что у меня тоже звездочки пропали. И с прототипом тут все норм у меня.

Comment: Чтобы код писался как есть, пользуйте кнопочку для написания кода (на панельке присутствует. И код будет даже раскрашен). Или перед спецсимволами - звёздочкой, подчёркиванием, слешем и чем-то там ещё, что пропадает, ставьте слеши - и всё будет ня)

Answer (score 0):

- Во первых - в функции `sum()` вы возвращаете указатель на локальный массив, что недопустимо. Добропорядочный компилятор вам должен об этом сказать.
- Во вторых - тип `P_Sum` не соответствует сигнатуре функции `sun()` которая в dll`ке.

Comment: все соответствует, тут просто HashCode еще не отредактировал код... там все нормально... и сюда ещё мой предыдущий комментарий.